# Listening for when Picasso is done downloading an image to use Palette

Tags: android, picasso, android-palette

I wanted to use the Palette library in Android. I am also using Picasso to load images into an imageview. Is there any way of knowing when Picasso is done loading the image so I can get the colors from the image in Palette?

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://urlForImage").placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder_image).into(imageView);
Palette.generateAsync(BITMAP, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                    //do stuff with palette...
                }
            });
```

Comment: See response at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072176/picasso-image-load-callback

Comment: Thanks! I knew I overlooked something... :)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".