# imgeview getdrawable is null

Tags: android, drawable

I have following code

```
if (imagesList.get(position).getImage() != null) {
                Picasso.with(context).load(imagesList.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.imgSlider);

            //View v = holder.imgSlider.getDrawable();
            if (holder.imgSlider != null) {
                BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) holder.imgSlider.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
                Bitmap blurredBitmap = blur(bitmap);
                holder.mediaBackground.setImageBitmap(blurredBitmap);
            }
            else{
                Log.e("img slider is null","");
            }
```

here i am getting drawable object value null. i dont uinderstand how to obtain the drawable value.
the above code is inside adapters istantiateItem method.

Please help me in this. thank you in advance

Comment: its a arraylist of type "profile media"

Comment: profile media is serializable class

Comment: use `into(android.widget.ImageView target, Callback callback)` and do your stuff in the callback

Comment: If `drawable`is null then maybe it's because Picasso works asynchronously: at the time where `Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();` is executed, the drawable has not yet been loaded.

Comment: ok let me try this

Comment: @0X0nosugar what is solution then?

Comment: sudarshan @pskink just provided the solution for you

Comment: ok @Alex i will try it

Comment: Do like pskink said - check e.g. this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28056058/5015207)

Comment: but actually `into(Target target)` is even better as you have to call `setImageBitmap` with the blurred bitmap

Comment: thank you so much @pskink and 0X0nosugar it works like charm. Thousand likes for your answer.

Comment: did you use `into(Target target)`?

Comment: @pskink yes into(Target target) was useful but into(target, callback) does the work here..

Comment: is it possible to achieve it by using into(Target) instead of into(target, callback)?

Comment: `into(Target target)` is better as it gives you the loaded `Bitmap` as a parameter in `onBitmapLoaded(android.graphics.Bitmap bitmap,
                    Picasso.LoadedFrom from)` method

Comment: @pskink then how can i get callback? if i use only into(Target target) but not into(Target target, Callback)

Comment: Target is a callback, see http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/Target.html