# how can i make the progressdialog stop after the data returns

Tags: android

```
package com.majd.volleyapp

class ImageAct : AppCompatActivity() {

    var url: String = "http://sdkas.com/logo.gif"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle ?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image)

        var pd = ProgressDialog(this)

        pd.setMessage("Please Wait....")

        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER)

        pd.show()

        Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(imageView)


    }
}
```

Comment: Check the onSuccess and onError callbacks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072176/picasso-image-load-callback. You can stop it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pd.dismiss(); This is the method for removing it.