# Can anybody tell me what is wrong with that line of code

Tags: android, multithreading, firebase

```
new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               try {
                   //Bitmap bitmap = Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(Uri.parse(mNewMember.getMemberImageUri())).resize(300, 300).get();
                   Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(mNewMember.getMemberImageUri()));
                   ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, stream);
                   byte[] imageData = stream.toByteArray();
                   FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
                           .child("member images\\")
                           .child(mNewMember.getMemberId() + ".jpg").putBytes(imageData);
               }catch (IOException e){Log.d("db","machhar");}
       }
       }.run();
```

So currently it is uploading an image to firebase storeage but if I uncomment the commented line and comment the line below it, then the image does not get uploaded and no error gets generated i also tried attaching failure listener , it also does not get called.
While both the lines returns a bitmap then why the first line(commented) does not work , and second line works.
 Also if I use the first line I have to run it one a background thread otherwise it produces error.

**Please explain**

Comment: 1st line replace with this line **`Bitmap bitmap = Picasso.with(context).load(url).get()`** and try.

Comment: `Runnable#.run()` will run on same thread not on separate thread . Create a new thread and then call `thread.start()`..

Comment: ADM you're right but before wrapping it inside the run method , there was an error now it there is no error "saying that i need to do it on separate thread, can you please explain why is that even when the thread is same

Comment: @Ali i want to resize because i don't want to put big image in firebase storage

Answer (score 1):

The commented line is Asynchronous and so the rest of your code will continue to execute immediately instead of waiting for it to complete.

You can use picasso with a completion callback in order to wait for the result.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072176/picasso-image-load-callback)

Comment: your answer is very helpful can you also explain why that line needs a separate thread to run , so before i wrap it inside run() method there was an error basically saying that "i need to run it on separate thread" , but ADM commented that it is same thread then why now the error is not there.

Comment: aslo please tell me which line should i use , i am asking this because the method MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap() is deprecated

Comment: also please tell me how to use that listener , if i use the first line